# Is it safe to delete ~/.cache/pip directory

Tags: pip

I have limited space on my server, and I am thinking to delete the cache of the PIP. I am not sure if its safe to delete or not.

```
ls  ~/.cache/pip/
```

Contains following dir/files.

```
http  selfcheck.json  wheels
```

### Version

```
$ pip -V
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

Please advise.

Comment: Probably yes. If you want to be on the safe side, just rename the directory. If you do not experience problems you can remove the renamed folder afterwards.

Comment: thank you :) i will try.

Comment: Any issue after deleting it?

Comment: To purge the cache, you can instead use the command: pip cache purge

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [pip's caching documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#caching) from version 6 you can use the *--no-cache-dir* option.

But that didn't help me as I was using a wrapper (pinax starter projects) that runs pip in the background to install several packages. Since I kept getting an pip.exceptions.HashErrors ('hashes don't match the requirement file) and I didn't want to temper with its code I renamed the pip cache folder and tried running my wrapper again. Once I noticed there weren't issues I proceeded to delete the entire cache pip folder. I haven't had any problem after that. So I can assume it is entirely a safe operation to delete pip's cache folder.

These are the locations where you can find your pip cache:

**Unix**

~/.cache/pip and it respects the XDG_CACHE_HOME directory.

**OS X**

~/Library/Caches/pip.

**Windows**

\pip\Cache

Comment: At least in Windows 7 and Windows 10, I find pip's cache in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\pip\cache.

Comment: Note: you can find pip's caching directory using this command `python -m pip cache dir` in Linux/MacOS, and `py -m pip cache dir` in Windows. See [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_cache/#pip-cache) for info

Answer (score 90):

[Since pip 20.1b1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/), which was released on 21 April 2020 and "added `pip cache` command for inspecting/managing pip’s wheel cache", you no longer need to. Instead, you can issue this command:

```
pip cache purge
```

The reference guide is here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_cache/
The corresponding [pull request is here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/6391).

Comment: Nice new feature. And `purge` does not remove my `http` cache, which is 400MB+ on my system macOS 10.15.4+pyenv+conda

Comment: Mine is at 4.1GB after doing 2 days of Unity ML setup and training...

Comment: It looks like this purge cmd now includes the http cache as of Oct 2020: https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/8910