# Is it safe to delete folder Cache/pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have messed up with my whole programming environment and I would like to delete `/Users/Solal/Library/Caches/pip/` so I am sure not reinstall bad versions of package.

Is it safe to do so?

Comment: In general it shouldn't cause too much harm to delete a cache other than the time it takes to rebuild. Similar question but for linux file structure instead of macos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39510975/4027401

edit: additionally you can always temporarily rename the directory. e.g. `pip_tmp` and make sure everything behaves as expected before you truly delete.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Is+it+safe+to+delete+cache

Answer (score 5):

It is safe to delete the user cache directory. It will simply cause `pip` to re-download all packages from PyPI. Do try `pip install --no-cache-dir ...` before you delete it to isolate your problem.

Comment: Newer `pip` versions comes with tooling such as `pip cache info/list` to inspect and `pip cache remove/purge` to clean up cache directories.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to delete it.

But it's better to **close all applications** to prevent any confusion of the programs accessing the cache.

so if you want to free up disk space, you can do it.