# How handle pip and pip cache in windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm stuck in pip installation process..

1.how can ignore pip cache

2.how can remove all packages for pip

3.can pip/cache folder deletion is safe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513597/is-it-safe-to-delete-cache-pip-directory

Comment: Each part of this question has been adressed before here on stackoverflow and can also be found in pip's documentation

Answer (score 2):

1. remove all packages

   `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y`
2. install any packages without pip cache

   `pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt`
3. removes all wheel files related to matplotlib from pip's cache

   `pip cache remove matplotlib`
4. to clear all wheel files from pip's cache.

   `pip cache purge`
5. configure pip to not use the cache "globally" (in all commands).

   `pip config set global.no-cache-dir false`

Comment: `xargs` is not an approach that works on windows